# Javascript focus() is not working in mobile browser on element that just entered the window from top, React functional component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mobile, focus

I've built a search bar dropdown as part of a navbar I'm working on in React. The search bar's starting position is above the window, top: -112px. When the search button on the nav is clicked, the search bar animation begins and the the drop down goes from top: -112px to top: 0. After the animation is complete and the 'shown' class is applied to the search bar container, a useEffect watching the displayClass value triggers and focuses on the search bar input field.

This works fine on desktop Chrome and Safari, but on mobile the input field does not focus once in view for either browser. I've tried setTimeouts of every length on the focus call to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

SearchBar component:

```
export const SearchBar = ({
  analyticsSearchBarSearchInput,
  display,
  history,
  onClose,
}) => {
  const [displayClass, setDisplayClass] = useState("");
  const [searchActive, setSearchActive] = useState(false);

  const prevDisplayRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    prevDisplayRef.current = display;
  });
  const prevDisplay = prevDisplayRef.current;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!prevDisplay && display) {
      onSearchOpen();
    } else if (prevDisplay && !display) {
      onSearchClose();
    }
  }, [display, prevDisplay]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (displayClass === "shown") {
      document.getElementById("search-bar-input").focus({
        preventScroll: true,
      });
    }
  }, [displayClass]);

  return (
    <ConditionalWrapper
      condition={displayClass === "shown"}
      wrapper={(children) => (
        <OutsideClick onClick={onClose}>{children}</OutsideClick>
      )}
    >
      <div className={`search-bar__container ${displayClass}`}>
        <div className="search-bar__left">
          <div className={`search-bar__search-icon${getSearchIconClass()}`} />
          <div className="search-bar__input">
            <SearchForm
              onSubmit={onSearchSubmit}
              searchActive={searchActive}
              setSearchActive={setSearchActive}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="search-bar__right">
          <div
            aria-label="Close search"
            className="search-bar__close-icon"
            onClick={onClose}
            onKeyDown={onClose}
            role="button"
            tabIndex={0}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </ConditionalWrapper>
  );

  function getSearchIconClass() {
    return searchActive ? " active" : "";
  }

  function onSearchClose() {
    setDisplayClass("hide");
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDisplayClass("");
    }, 300);

    enableBodyScroll();
    document.body.removeEventListener("touchmove", touchMoveCallback, {
      passive: false,
    });
  }

  function onSearchOpen() {
    setDisplayClass("show");
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDisplayClass("shown");
    }, 200);

    disableBodyScroll();
    document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMoveCallback, {
      passive: false,
    });
  }

  function onSearchSubmit(usersInput) {
    const hostUrl = window.location.host;
    const pageNumber = 1;
    const searchUrl = `${hostUrl}/search?query=${usersInput}&page=${pageNumber}`;
    if (displayClass === "shown" && usersInput !== "") {
      Promise.resolve(
        analyticsSearchBarSearchInput(hostUrl, usersInput, searchUrl)
      ).then(() => {
        onClose();
        history.push(`/search?query=${usersInput}&page=${pageNumber}`);
      });
    }
  }
};

const ConditionalWrapper = ({ condition, wrapper, children }) =>
  condition ? wrapper(children) : children;

const touchMoveCallback = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

SearchBar Form Component:

```
export const SearchForm = ({ onSubmit, searchActive, setSearchActive }) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    search !== "" ? setSearchActive(true) : setSearchActive(false);
  }, [search, setSearchActive]);

  return (
    <div className="search-bar__form-container">
      <form action="#" onSubmit={onSearchSubmit} className="search-bar__form">
        <input
          autoComplete="off"
          name="search"
          className="search-bar__input"
          id="search-bar-input"
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Search"
          type="search"
          value={search}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        />
      </form>
      {searchActive && (
        <div
          aria-label="Search submit"
          className="search-bar__submit-button"
          onClick={onSearchSubmit}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
          role="button"
          tabIndex={0}
        >
          SEARCH&gt;
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );

  function handleChange(event) {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
  }

  function onSearchSubmit() {
    onSubmit(search);
    setSearch("");
    document.activeElement.blur();
  }

  function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      onSearchSubmit();
    }
  }
};
```

Styling:

```
.search-bar {
  &__close-icon {
    background: url("/images/icons/close.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 26px;
    transition: all 80ms ease-out;
    width: 26px;

    &:hover {
      background: url("/images/icons/close-hover.png") no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
    }
  }

  &__container {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    color: #c5c5c5;
    display: flex;
    height: 112px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: -112px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1020;

    &.show {
      animation: searchFadeIn 200ms ease-out;
    }

    &.shown {
      top: 0;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
    }

    &.hide {
      animation: searchFadeOut 300ms ease-in;
    }
  }

  @keyframes searchFadeIn {
    0% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
    }

    50% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
    }

    100% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
      top: 0px;
    }
  }

  @keyframes searchFadeOut {
    0% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
      top: 0;
    }

    50% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
    }

    100% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
      top: -75px;
    }
  }

  &__icon {
    background: url("/images/icons/search.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 24px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 24px;
  }

  &__input {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #333333;
    flex: 1;
    font-family: Setimo;
    font-size: 42px;
    line-height: 1.24;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    max-width: 321px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }

  &__form {
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  }

  &__form-container {
    display: flex;
  }

  &__left {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }

  &__right {
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-right: 40px;
  }

  &__search-icon {
    background: url("/images/icons/search-grey.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 24px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 24px;

    &.active {
      background: url("/images/icons/search.png") no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
    }
  }

  &__submit-button {
    align-self: flex-end;
    color: #9a9a9a;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 1;
    font-family: Setimo;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.64;
    letter-spacing: 3.5px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    transition: all 80ms ease-out;
    width: 81px;

    &:hover {
      color: #333333;
    }
  }
}

.search-icon {
  &__container {
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transition: all 80ms ease-out;
    width: 97px;

    &:hover .search-icon__text {
      color: #7d7be4;
    }

    &:hover .search-icon__icon {
      background: url("/images/icons/search-hover.png") no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
    }
  }

  &__icon {
    background: url("/images/icons/search.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
  }

  &__text {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Setimo;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 3.5px;
    line-height: 1.64;
  }
}

::placeholder {
  color: #c5c5c5;
}

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type="text"]::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

input[type="text"]::-ms-reveal {
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 959px) {
  .search-bar {
    &__container {
      height: 80px;
      top: -80px;
    }

    &__form {
      margin: 0;
    }

    &__input {
      font-size: 32px;
      max-width: 225px;
    }

    &__left {
      padding-left: 30px;
    }

    &__right {
      padding-right: 30px;
    }

    &__search-icon {
      padding-right: 14px;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .search-bar {
    &__close-icon {
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
    }

    &__container {
      height: 64px;
      top: -64px;
    }

    &__form {
      margin: 0;
    }

    &__input {
      font-size: 24px;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      max-width: 175px;
    }

    &__left {
      padding-left: 16px;
    }

    &__right {
      padding-right: 16px;
    }

    &__search-icon {
      padding-right: 10px;
    }

    &__submit-button {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```